# memcpy in opencl 1.1

Tags: opencl, c99

Is there any mechanisms like memcpy in opencl. I want to copy a struct of pointers on the gpu, and as we cannot copy them directly from host to device, so I decide to create sepeprate buffer for each pointer and then put all of them together in one struct on the device. So, I wanted to have a mechanism like `memcpy` to copy the data from one buffer to other one. Is there anything like that?

```
struct Grid_gpu {
  cl_uint3  dims;
  cl_uint* elements_beg_index;
  cl_uint n_element_cells;
  cl_uint* element_cells;
};
```

Comment: If you want to point to global memory, there is no way to do this. Definitely not in opencl 1.2 and lower; probably not the newer versions either.

Comment: @mfa So, just by iterating on all the elements of array and copy them element by element, it is possible but I wanted to know if is it possible to do that as a big block.

Comment: Do you need to copy this buffer from inside a kernel, or can the host initiate the memcpy?

Comment: @jprice If it is possible in opencl, it would be nice if I can do that with host. But as I understood it is not possible to copy such a struct on the gpu by host.

Comment: If you just want to copy data from one OpenCL buffer to another, you can use `clEnqueueCopyBuffer`. I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve with this struct of pointers however.

Comment: @jprice so, I have some data in my C++ code which is of `std::vector<std::vector>>` type, and I want to transfer it to the gpu. I am doing that using this struct. But as `elements_beg_index` has been `new`ed, we cannot copy it on the device using `clEnqueuWriteBuffer` or `clCreateBuffer`. So, I just copy the data of each pointer of this struct on the device seprately and then create the struct again on the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to do that I defined a struct on my device as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    uint3 dims;
    __global uint* element_begIndices;
    __global uint n_element_cells;
    __global uint* element_cells;
} Grid;
```

Then I just used the following kernel to fill the memory which is of type `Grid`:

```
// a kernel to fill a grid acceleration structure.
__kernel void fill_grid_accel(
    uint3 dims,
    __global uint* element_begIndices,
    uint n_element_cells,
    __global uint* element_cells,
    __global Grid* grid){

    grid->dims.x = dims.x;
    grid->dims.y = dims.y;
    grid->dims.z = dims.z;


    grid->element_begIndices = element_begIndices;
    grid->n_element_cells = n_element_cells;
    grid->element_cells = element_cells;
}
```

Now, the `grid` memory contains the pointer is filled with required data.s